# Error with Pods in React Native monorepo using Turborepo and Yarn Workspaces

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, yarn-workspaces

Here's a suggestion for a Stack Overflow question description and title to help you open an issue with your React Native monorepo using Turborepo and Yarn workspaces:

Title: Error with Pods in React Native monorepo using Turborepo and Yarn Workspaces

Description:

I'm trying to set up a monorepo for a React Native project using Turborepo and Yarn Workspaces, but I'm encountering an error with Pods. The error message is:

```
An error occurred while processing the post-install hook of the Podfile.
```

No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ../node_modules/react-native/package.json

I've tried various approaches to resolve the issue, such as symlinking the node_module/react-native directory, but so far nothing has worked. I'm hoping to find a solution to this issue, or to better understand what might be causing it.

Has anyone else encountered this error when using Turborepo and Yarn Workspaces in a React Native monorepo, and if so, how did you resolve it?

Comment: I'm also encountering this issue.

Answer (score 11):

This happens, because you have to tell Cocoapods where to find the react native package. Per default it will look one dir above (./..) which is not correct after re-organizing your codebase with yarn workspaces.

There are two solutions to this. You can go either way.

1. Change where yarn puts the node modules
2. Changes where CocoaPods looks for the node_modules

### Change where yarn puts the node modules

This can be achieved with the `noHoist`option in the top package json.

```json
...
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": [
      "./apps/*",
      "./packages/*"
    ],
  "nohoist": [
      "**/react-native",
      "**/react-native/**"
    ]
  },
...
```

(you need to delete node_modules folders and lock files for this to take effect)

Now, if you re-install your node modules, react-native will appear in your app project directory as usual and CocoaPods will be able to find it

### Change where CocoaPods looks for the node_modules

If you moved your project like this app => apps/app then you have to change 3 things in the Podfile

- 1/2: Add "../../" to `require_relative`, should be at line 2 and 3 in your podfile
- 3: Add `react_native_path` argument to `react_native_post_install`

```rb
require_relative '../../../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

...

   react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      react_native_path = "../../../node_modules/react-native",
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
```

Comment: Solved for my project - Lerna / NX monorepo with yarn workspaces

Comment: Instead of `../..` I had to add `../../..` to `require_relative`.